# Typescript error handler

Tags: error-handling, typescript, angular-2+, rxjs

I wrote a function in Typescript which takes required parameters, optional parameters and parameters with default value. I want to use this function for error handling of http requests. I am not sure, if my solution is good, so I wanted to know the opinion of the Code Review community.

Here is my function:

```
  public handleError<T>(
    operation: string = 'operation',
    customErrorMessage: string,
    valueToReturn: T,
    logError = true,
    showSnackbar?: boolean,
    showHttpErrorResponse?: boolean
  ): (error: any) => Observable<any> {
    return (error: any): Observable<T | Error> => {
      if (logError) {
        console.error(error.message);
      }

      if (showSnackbar) {
        if (showHttpErrorResponse) {
          this.snackbar.open(error.message, 'OK');
        } else {
          this.snackbar.open(customErrorMessage, 'OK');
        }

      }

      return showHttpErrorResponse ? of(new Error(error.message)) : of(valueToReturn as T);
    };
  }
```

Here is an example of calling:

```
this.httpClient.get('/', { observe: 'response', responseType: 'text' }).pipe(
      catchError(
        this.errorService.handleError('getSysName', '', null, true, false, true)
      )
    );
```

**My Questions**:

1. How is the selections of the parameter types (usage of required, optional and default parameters)? If it is not good, how would you improve it?
2. How is the naming of the parameters?
3. How is the order of the parameters? If it is not good, how would you order the parameters?
4. Do you have also improvement suggestions for the body of the function?
5. Do you have completely different suggestions for improvement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding of your approach here is to handle errors, which may occur when sending a request to one (of your) server. This function should log and/or display a snackbar depending on the parameters that were passed before. This leads us to your first three questions:

### Answers to questions 1-3

- operation: I noticed that the operation is unused and can be removed, what is it even used for? Why is the default value 'operation'?
- customErrorMessage: So the custom message could basically be an empty string ("") which would leave the snackbar which pops-up empty with I guess an 'OK' button?! This seems like bad UX or a bug. You may want to use something like `customErrorMessage: string | undefined` and explicitly check that the string is not empty. Also see [1]
- valueToReturn: We are handling errors, which may occur, why should this method return a value? Which value anyway? Again, is `null` a good approach here as well (maybe see [1])? Also see [2]
- logError: I don't like where this is placed, why is the first parameter a default parameter and why is this a default parameter placed in between (see [3]) - What do you think about an optional parameter called `disabledLog?: boolean`? When passed true, this parameter disables the logging otherwise everything gets logged
- showSnackbar, showHttpErrorResponse: Those are very self-explanatory I like them, also that those are the last parameters based on their signature is good!

### Answer to question 4

I'll concentrate on the function body for now, leaving out the rest.

The check whether or not to log is a good approach, this seems fine.

```js
      if (logError) {
        console.error(error.message);
      }
```

This looks like a bit of arrow code https://blog.codinghorror.com/flattening-arrow-code/.

```js
      if (showSnackbar) {
        if (showHttpErrorResponse) {
          this.snackbar.open(error.message, 'OK');
        } else {
          this.snackbar.open(customErrorMessage, 'OK');
        }
      }
```

Let's consider the following, which focusses on readability considering previously linked article:

```js
if (showSnackbar) {
  const content = showHttpErrorResponse ? error.message : customErrorMessage;
  this.snackbar.open(content, 'OK');
}
```

The same as before, we could try to factor out same things

```js
return showHttpErrorResponse ? of(new Error(error.message)) : of(valueToReturn as T);
```

Which could look like this:

```js
const returnValue = showHttpErrorResponse ? new Error(error.message) : valueToReturn;
return of(returnValue);
```

A follow-up question here is: Why does the showHttpErrorResponse dictate whether we return a custom value or Error here? This is not clear from a function signature point of view.

### Question 5:

I would like to use this question for two things, first, why is the return value of `handleError` at first: `(error: any) => Observable<any>` and later it is `(error: any) => Observable<T | Error>`, I'd suggest to align those to values. The last thing to finalize this post, this is what I'd come up with considering the things I've noted. And on top of that, I've decided to change the signature to be an object, which makes the boolean parameters and null/undefined params more readable.

```js
  handleError<T>(prop: {
    customErrorMessage: string | undefined,
    customReturnValue: T | undefined,
    showSnackbar?: boolean,
    showHttpErrorResponse?: boolean,
    disableLogging?: boolean }
  ): (error: any) => Observable<T | Error> {
    return (error: any): Observable<T | Error> => {
      if (!disableLogging) {
        console.error(error.message);
      }

      if (showSnackbar) {
        const content = showHttpErrorResponse ? error.message : customErrorMessage;
        this.snackbar.open(content, 'OK');
      }

      const returnValue = showHttpErrorResponse ? new Error(error.message) : customReturnValue;
      return of(returnValue);
    };
  }
```

With following usage:

```js
this.errorService.handleError({
  customErrorMessage: undefined,
  customReturnValue: null,
  showSnackbar: true,
  showHttpErrorResponse: false,
  disableLogging: false
})
```

#### ------ Appendix ------

[1]: Checking that a string is not empty, is also possible with typings to some extend. Something I scribbled quickly was something like:

```js
type NotEmptyString<T extends string> = `${T}` extends "" ? never : T;
type X = NotEmptyString<""> // X resolves to never
type Y = NotEmptyString<" "> // Y resolves to " "
```

[2]: Returning null could be a problematic approach and could potentially cause Runtime exceptions. I for myself try to reduce the usage of null and rather explicitly type my functions to return either a value OR undefined.

[3]: In general (across multiple languages, independent of syntax) default parameters come last. This is to avoid signatures like: `foo(undefined,undefined,undefined,requiredParamVal,undefined,undefined)`
Consider this example

```js
const foo = (a: number, bar = 1) => {}
foo(10)
const foofoo = (a = 1, bar: string) => {}
foofoo(undefined, "")
```